# usb crc5 11 bit check function

Tags: c, usb

I have the following data from which I want to build the crc5.

```
address: 0x19, endp: 0x1, and crc 0x19. 

value1 = convert_lsb(0x19) >> 1;
value2 = convert_lsb(0x1);
crc = crc5_11bit_usb(value1 << 4 | (value2 >> 4));
```

The crc5 result regarding the tool with addr 0x19 and endp 0x1 should be 0x19.

What is wrong with the code?

If I do the same with similiar data but the endp is 0xa the result is correct.

```
value1 = convert_lsb(0x3a) >> 1;
value2 = (convert_lsb(0xa));
crc = crc5_11bit_usb(value1 << 4 | (value2 >> 4));
```

The data comes from a tool to analyse usb and I want to build the crc5 manually.

Example code on
https://godbolt.org/z/Wqv1Mxnxj

Answer (score 0):

The data are read from left to right therefore the endpoint is in front of the address and not at the end.